# Can't call parent method properties from inheritance class in php

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I'am begginer in OOP PHP. I have code like this

```
class Index 
{
    public $activepage = true;
    public $url;
    public $page;

    function __construct()
    {
        if ($this->activepage) {
            $this->url = "Yes";
            $this->page = "Home";
        } else {
            $this->url = "No";
            $this->page = "Index";
        }

    }


    public function show()
    {
        return $this->page;
    }


    public function showTest()
    {
        return "test";
    }
}

class Home extends Index
{

    function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->show();
    }
}

$page = new Home;
```

My questions is :
Why I have blank page when I invoke Home class?

But when I change constructor in Home class like this `echo $this->showTest();`, it works. and displaying "test" on screen.

and what actually diferrent between my show method and showTest method in Index class?

Comment: Is your home object intatiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a `__construct()` in the `Home` class it overrides the construct from the parent class `Index`.

You can invoke the parent construct manually with:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    echo $this->show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gab. It's work and very helping me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can call Parent class method like;

```
parent::show()
```

Comment: when I put your answer in my home class  constructor I still have blank screen. Thank you very much Pramod for your answer.